# An ODE with simple condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I'm working about this :

> Let $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)$ be a twice differentiable and continuous function such that :
>   $$f''(x)^2\leq f'(x)+x^2$$
>   With $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$
>
> Prove that $f(x)^2\leq \frac{x^3}{4 \pi^2}(f(x)+\frac{x^3}{3})$

My friend tells me that we can use the Wirtinger's inequality but I don't see how...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks in advance for your time